# Live Streaming Service Development

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming

I am about to develop a service that involves an interactive audio live streaming. Interactive in the sense that a moderator can have his stream paused and upon request, stream audio coming from one of his listeners (during the streaming session).

Its more like a Large Pipe where what flows through but the water can come in from only one of many small pipes connected to it at a time with a moderator assigned to each stream controlling which pipe is opened. I know nothing about media streaming, I dont know if a cloud service provides an interactive programmable solution such as this.

I am a programmer and I will be able to program the logic involved in such interaction. The issue is **I am a novice to media streaming**, don't have any knowledge if its technologies and various software used on the server for such purpose, **are there any books that can introduce on to the technologies employed in media streaming**, **and I am trying to avoid using Flash**,?

Clients could be web or mobile. I dont think I will have any problem with integrating with client system. My issue is implementing the server side

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively programming a switcher.  Basically, you need to be able to switch from one audio stream to the other.  With uncompressed PCM, this is very simple.  As long as the sample rates and bit depth are equal, cut the audio on any frame (which is sample-accurate) and switch to the other.  You can resample audio and apply dithering to convert between different sample rates and bit depths.

The complicated part is when lossy codecs get involved.  On a simlar project, I have gone down the road of trying to stitch streams together, and I can tell you that it is nearly impossible, even with something as simple as MP3.  (The bit reservoir makes things difficult.)  Plus, it sounds as if you will be supporting a wide variety of devices, meaning you likely won't be able standardize on a codec anyway.  The best thing to do is take multiple streams and decode them at the mix point of your system.  Then, you can switch from stream to stream easily with PCM.

At the output of your system, you'll want to re-encode to some lossy codec.

Due to latency, you don't typically want the server doing this switching.  The switching should be done at the desk of the person encoding the stream so that way they can cue it accurately.  Just write something that does all of the switching and encoding, and use SHOUTcast/Icecast for hosting your streams.

Comment: If I understand you very well, the streaming isn't really the issue the issue is more on encoding/decoding and switching. But I am a newbe in audio processing, dont have any ideas about how to go about programming switchers, doing all the encoding things etc. Are there any resource, books or tutorials that can take me from ground up into the world of media/audio processing and programming. Python/Java programming, preferably python is what i will like to use since its going to be hosted on the internet

Comment: Encoding/decoding is handled by codecs outside of your application.  If it were me, I would just pipe to FFMPEG for the codecs.  For the rest, you just need to switch from one stream to the other.